# Display bug when using BezierPath to round corners of a UITableViewCell's subview

Tags: ios, swift

Even though I have solved this, I still want to ask the cause and/or the solution for this problem. Because most probably I will need a better way in the future. The solution I have will be posted at the end of the post.

The problem is that when I adjust the width constraint of the view (container) of the label, make it longer, the backgroundColor does not fill the whole view (or rather, the view (container) is being cut, but in the debug view hierarchy, the container is equal to the imageView's trailing. See the screenshot:

[image]

The bug is caused by using `UIBezierPath`:

```
/// Round the corner radius with bezier path.
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

I am used to autolayout and rounding corners using `UIBezierPath` and `layer.cornerRadius`. If I don't use `UIBezierPath`, the bug does not occur.

One more info is that I usually call a method in a cell called `setupCell()` during the `cellForRow`. And in that method, I determine stuff like constraint values depending on a data. Then update the constraints.

**What I've tried:**

1. Round the corners using `UIBezierPath` inside the overriden `drawRect()` of the cell.
2. Round the corners using `UIBezierPath` inside the overriden `func layoutSubviews()`.
3. Put everything in the main thread.
4. Call `self.setNeedsDisplay()` after determining the new width constant of the view (container).

**Current solution that I have implemented and that works:**

Don't use `UIBezierPath` and rather `layer.cornerRadius`, using this will round all the corners, but since the view (container) is at the bottom and trailing of the imageView, I just add an offset/inset to make it outside the imageView's bottom and trailing, and imageView has a its `clipsToBounds` set to true.

So the question is: why does this happen, and what could be the other way to solve it?

The purpose of the question is for the future cases, like suppose the view (container) is at the center of the cell, and the topLeft corner is the only one to be rounded? :)

Thanks!

Comment: if you're able to limit the target OS to `iOS 11` and above, you can add a corner mask to the layer directly (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/2877488-maskedcorners). I'm aware that this doesn't answer your question - but it may help solving the problem that you might face in the future...

Comment: Thanks! But the minimum iOS version of the project is 10.0 :)